# Difficulty with javascript promise and setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am having trouble the following javascript. I am using the jQuery framework.

This code works the first time, displaying the date, temperature and humidity corectly but the second time it runs i get this error message;

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

Here is the code;

```
var gettingTemperature = $.post("/get_temperature.php");

setInterval(gettingTemperature, 5000);

gettingTemperature.then(function (data) {

        $('#date').text(data.date);
        $('#temperature').html(data.temperature + "&#8451;");
        $('#humidity').text(data.humidity + "%");

    }, function () {
        console.log('Unable to access temperature model');
    }
);
```

Comment: I had christiandev, I couldn't find the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gettingTemperature` doesn't represent the call to $.post() but rather the result of calling $.post() which is the jqXHR object

setInterval expects a function reference as a first parameter but you hand over the jqXHR object. That's why you run the $.post() once (with the very first line) and setInterval fails

```
var gettingTemperature = function {
    $.post("/get_temperature.php").then(function (data) {

        $('#date').text(data.date);
        $('#temperature').html(data.temperature + "&#8451;");
        $('#humidity').text(data.humidity + "%");
    }, function () {
        console.log('Unable to access temperature model');
    });
};

gettingTemperature();
setInterval(gettingTemperature, 5000);
```

Comment: Is **gettingTemperature** a promise? I taught I could create a promise out of the ajax call and then run it several times.

Comment: A Promise cannot be run. And yes, jqXHR implemets the Promise interface and (therefore) "is" a Promise

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to pass a method into `setInterval`, but you are passing a promise. Usually in this scenario you would just pass the success or fail function into the `$.post` call, but if you really need to use the promise, then that's fine too. Since you don't know exactly when the `$.post` call will return (i.e. how long it will take), you shouldn't be using `setInterval`, because if it takes longer than the interval, you could end up with multiple concurrent requests, and that isn't very useful.

What most people do in this scenario is to wait until the first `$.post` requests finishes, then in the `complete` handler, call the `$.post` again. That way you will only ever have one request out at a time.

Comment: I don't want to flood my server with requests. How would I get the complete handler to wait a period of time before calling the $.post again?

Comment: Use `setTimeout`. It's similar to the `setInterval` function, but it only executes the provided function once.